# Transferring Django from windows to ubuntu

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, ini, configparser

I have written a project in windows with Django, It works well in windows, I wanted to transfer it to Ubuntu, first I installed the python3 and then made a virtualenv,
activated it and installed django and required packages, I got some errors but the main irritating one is that, I have a INI file, I use the configobj to read it, it works well in windows but in Ubuntu it give 'Key error' here is my code:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
ConfigPath = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'Vars.ini')
ConfigParser = ConfigObj(ConfigPath)
print(ConfigParser['FileNames']['MotionName'])
```

and here is the file:

```
[FileNames]
MotionName = test1
```

I also tried to use only lowercase words but still no chance.

Comment: What is the message in the KeyError exception raised saying what key is at fault? Share the traceback

Comment: KeyError at /
'FileNames'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.1.105:8000/
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
'FileNames'

Comment: basically means the key `FileNames` is not present in ConfigParser. What version of Python were you running this on in Windows?

Comment: windows : python 3.6.6 , django 2.0.6  Ubuntu: python 3.6.5 , django 2.1

Comment: Can you print the ConfigParser variabole and show what it returns.

Comment: My thinking is either the `ConfigObj(ConfigPath)` returned an object with nothing or somehow key `FileNames` was not read. I suggest adding more debug logging in this script e.g. print `ConfigPath` to confirm the join gave you location of your `ini` file also print out contents of `ConfigParser` to see what was read in

Comment: I tried in windows again and did print(ConfigParser ) and it printed the whole file but did it in Ubuntu and it printed nothing, it seems it can't find the file, my folders have lower and upper case words, will it have any affect? ConfigPath is also ok.

Comment: No that should not be a problem. What is the value of `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` is it the same as you `Vars.ini` path relative to where the script will run from?

Comment: I printed the ConfigPath and it is correct. It is: /home/Myuser/WifiSoftware/MainProject/Files/Vars.ini

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it, my file was Vars.INI, windows would recognize it since it would take INI as extension but Ubuntu was looking for Vars.ini and it couldn't find it so I change the name from Vars.INI to Vars.ini.